# Use the Fetch API to fetch multiple elements

Tags: javascript, fetch

The code below uses the JavaScript fetch API to grab a section from the destination URL and pull it into a div.

This simple example works great, but instead of grabbing a single DOM element, is it possible to grab multiple? For example, let's say I wanted to grab the three children of `<div class="row-fluid" />` and append them to my `<div />`?

```js
fetch("https://enable-cors.org/")
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const htmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
    const section = htmlDocument.documentElement.querySelector("section");
    document.querySelector("div").appendChild(section);
})
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the fetch request you actually grabbed entire DOM not a single element, what you do inside of the callback function of the second `.then` matters. There you parsed text and used `querySelector` to select this element in particular.

If i were to change the selector to that that matches your criteria and requests its children i could append them one by one.

```js
fetch("https://enable-cors.org/")
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const htmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
    const section = htmlDocument.documentElement.querySelector("div[class='row-fluid']");
    Array.from(section.children) // turn node list into array
      .slice(0,3) // get only first 3 childrem
      .forEach(child => document.querySelector("div").appendChild(child));
})
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Please take a note of the fact that image urls are relative which is why they won't render properly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this answer allows me to turn this into function with an optional argument for getting children, so it's very handy.

Answer (score 1):

Define a new variable for second element which have row-fluid class name. And use innerHTML insted of appendChild. For images you can use base tag.

```js
fetch("https://enable-cors.org/")
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const htmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
    const section = htmlDocument.documentElement.querySelector("section").outerHTML
  const section2 = htmlDocument.documentElement.getElementsByClassName("row-fluid")[0].outerHTML;

    document.querySelector("div").innerHTML += section + section2
});
```

```html
<div></div>
```